# mounting local home directory in Rstudio docker?

Tags: docker

I installed rstudio server by running:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER='MY_USER' -e PASSWORD='MY_PASSWORD' rocker/hadleyverse
```

I would like to link (mount?) my local home directory (or a folder) to that docker container. Is that possible? how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `-v` or `--volume` to mount directories into a container. For example:

```
docker run -d \
           -p 8787:8787 \
           -e USER='MY_USER' \
           -e PASSWORD='MY_PASSWORD' \
           -v $HOME:/src \
           rocker/hadleyverse
```

Now your container will have a folder named `/src` with the contents of your local home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-v` flag:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER='MY_USER' -e PASSWORD='MY_PASSWORD' -v $HOME:/data rocker/hadleyverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation entitled [Sharing files with host machine](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine) in the wiki.