# Cant find local volume on Docker rocker

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I can't seem to solve this question, even though it seems that this has been answered here:

I am trying to run the [rocker/tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tensorflow) Docker container in Ubuntu 20.04 but I also need it to access the following folder `/home/au687614/Documents/LUCAS_ML`

So I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432299/mount-local-volume-accessible-to-r-rstudio-in-docker-tidyverse) and run this:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v $(pwd):/home/au687614/Documents/LUCAS_ML:/home/rstudio/LOOKATMEEE -e ROOT=TRUE rocker/tensorflow
```

This however gets me the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /home/rstudio/LOOKATMEEE.
See 'docker run --help'
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Your syntax for `-v` is wrong, you have specified three path with `x:y:z`, when the argument takes to `x:y`. Just remove `$(pwd)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct syntax would be:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=yourpassword -v /path/to/your/local/folder:/home/rstudio/LOOKATMEEE:rw rocker/tensorflow
```

This comes from [this e-book](https://rap4mads.eu/self-contained-raps-with-docker.html#docker-essentials) where you can find explanations about the syntax and other Docker essentials explained.

Comment: Hey @Barbara, I tried this, but although the new folder LOOKATMEE appears in the session, it does not have any of the contents I have in my local folder, any idea of why?

Comment: I am not a Docker expert but I would say that this command only mounts the `LOOKATMEEE` directory. Then, you can access it from RStudio, for instance, and save files in it. These files will automatically be saved also in the local directory you specified.

Comment: Sorry @Barbara Gendron, it actually worked Cheers